# Galera Cluster MariaDB down due too high CPU

Tags: mariadb, galera, haproxy

We have 3 nodes of MariaDB Galera Cluster runing with 2 HAproxy for loadbalancing. Recently, all 3 nodes of MariaDB crashed . I noticed that CPU was really high like 99% or 100% on the 3 nodes before the crash. Is it possible that all nodes crashed because of high utilisation of CPU ?
Who has already seen a similar case before please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Without any more information, no one can help you. MariaDB version? OS and version? Messages from the error log? Is MariaDB the only application running on the nodes? Could MariaDB have been killed by the OOM killer?

Comment: Does the high usage correspond with a change in Web request volume/nature or similar application changes?

Comment: Did it really "crash"?  Or did you they seem to "never finish"?  High CPU comes from poorly formed queries or poor indexes.  Let's see a couple of the naughty queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.